# How to check with mypy that types are *not* compatible

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking, pyright

Imagine I am writing a little Python library with one (nonsense) function:

```
def takes_a_str(x: str) -> str:
    if x.startswith("."):
        raise RuntimeError("Must not start with '.'")
    return x + ";"
```

For runtime tests of the functionality, I can check it behaves as expected under both correct conditions (e.g. `assert takes_a_str('x')=='x;'`) and also error conditions (e.g. `with pytest.raises(RuntimeError): takes_a_str('.')`).

If I want to check that I have not made a mistake with the type hints, I can also perform positive tests: I can create a little test function in a separate file and run mypy or pyright to see that there are no errors:

```
def check_types() -> None:
    x: str = takes_a_str("")
```

But I also want to make sure my type hints are not too loose, by checking that some negative cases fail as they ought to:

```
def should_fail_type_checking() -> None:
    x: dict = takes_a_str("")
    takes_a_str(2)
```

I can run mypy on this and observe it has errors where I expected, but this is not an automated solution. For example, if I have 20 cases like this, I cannot instantly see that they have all failed, and also may not notice if other errors are nestled amongst them.

Is there a way to ask the type checker to pass, and ONLY pass, where a type conversion does not match? A sort of analogue of `pytest.raises()` for type checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mypy and pyright both support emitting errors when they detect unnecessary error-suppressing comments. You can utilise this to do an equivalent of `pytest.raises`, failing a check when things *are* type-safe. The static type-checking options that need to be turned on are:

- mypy: [`warn_unused_ignores = True`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-warn_unused_ignores) / [`--warn-unused-ignores`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-warn-unused-ignores) / [`strict = True`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-strict) / [`--strict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict)
- pyright: `reportUnnecessaryTypeIgnoreComment` (see [Pyright: Type Check Diagnostics Settings](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=type-check-diagnostics-settings))

Demonstration ([mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=warn-unused-ignores&gist=ba57eded18462d120ebbd32ae2cbb3c1), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?reportUnnecessaryTypeIgnoreComment=true&code=CYUwZgBALghg1iAzgfRsxUBOAKAHgLgg0wEoIBaAPiK3wFgAoCZiAS0lwDoMZMpEA7qygALbACJO4kvSYt5mGK0QgIAJQCuAOyisAtiACimTAHsc4gLIaMELaag1ejoaIgByTu%2BmMFIKBqYWhC4EADUEOIA3OKMjKCQiCKmGgA2wMhgSqnIUACeAA4gyADGIiAlcKxaAObYZFQQAHKmWiCy8gQQwKwljgC80PBIqOhYEtLMAMQQBXmYrDUiUISL9pggANobBeZQAIKIiGsGOgAqhSAAur4ssAgoaMTYAExkEDNzC0srbDXrWx2e32mBqGlOUAuRRuDHi4AgZQqcFyl0Q9Qo1BabQ6LC6xAgg3uIye43Ekw%2Bs3mi2Wq3%2B5kBIF2fEOx3%2BEKh1yAA)):

```py
def should_fail_type_checking() -> None:
    # no errors
    x: dict = takes_a_str("")  # type: ignore[assignment] OR # pyright: ignore[reportAssignmentType]
    takes_a_str(2)  # type: ignore[arg-type] OR # pyright: ignore[reportArgumentType]

def check_types() -> None:
    # Failures with mypy and pyright
    # mypy: Unused "type: ignore" comment  [unused-ignore]
    # pyright: Unnecessary "# pyright: ignore" rule: "reportAssignmentType"
    x: str = takes_a_str("")  # type: ignore[assignment] OR # pyright: ignore[reportAssignmentType]
```

Notes:

- The exact error-suppression code should be provided, as if you don't provide specific codes, mypy and pyright will suppress all errors on a line; in your context, this would be equivalent of doing `pytest.raises(BaseException)`.
- If you're supporting multiple type checkers (e.g. both mypy and pyright), prefer a mypy diagnostic `type: ignore[<mypy error code>]` - The comment character sequence `# type: ignore...` is a Python-typing-compliant code which should be recognised by all type-checkers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay accepting, I wanted to try it out first. That works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to ask the type checker to pass, and ONLY pass, where a type conversion does not match? A sort of analogue of `pytest.raises()` for type checking?

I don't think that's possible with normal tools, for the same reason that there's no way to ask `python.exe` to only accept a file if there's a *syntax error* in a certain function.

The purpose of type checking is to verify that the program is self consistent. It does not check specific instances and gives you a score, that's the job of test suites.

If you really want to ensure that your negative examples always fail type checking, you can always script calls to `mypy` and check for the reported errors, on a per-file basis. Not as clean as `pytest.raises()`, but much simpler than having a framework for testing type annotations at runtime.